Проблема с откликом raycaster three.js
Проблема в чем:
-Есть 3 куба и по клику на них они передвигаются, при повторном возвращаются в начальное положение
НО! если я нажимаю не на куб, а на любое другое место на экране то мне выдает ошибку что такой объект не найден.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'object')

как мне реализовать реагирование только на клик по кубу.(отлавливать и проглатывать ошибку я не хочу)
Я думаю проблема не в самом raycaster, а в window.addEventListener который и не находит куб на window
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import TWEEN from 'three/examples/jsm/libs/tween.module';
import './style.css';

const scene = new THREE.Scene(); // сцена 


const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 ); // камера и ее размеры

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(); 
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );  // рендерим 
renderer.setClearColor(0x9BCFFF);
const canvas = document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const controls =  new OrbitControls(camera,canvas);
controls.enableDamping = true;
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );  //геомертрия куба
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );  //материал - цвет
const material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x039BCF } );
const material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x50D445 } );
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

const tpiyg = new THREE.TetrahedronGeometry(1,0);
const trh = new THREE.Mesh(tpiyg,material2);
trh.position.y = 2;
scene.add(trh);
const cube1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material1 );
const cube2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material2 ); // собираем куб 

const grupa = new  THREE.Group();

cube.position.x = -3;
cube2.position.x = 3;

grupa.add(cube,cube1,cube2);
console.log('позиция куба:',cube.position);
console.log('позиция куба1:',cube1.position);
console.log('позиция куба2:',cube2.position);
let mouseX = 0,mouseY = 0;
//клик
let stat = 0;
let stat1 = 0;
let stat2 = 0;
const cast = new THREE.Raycaster();
console.log(cast);

const handclick = (event)=>{
    const pointer = new THREE.Vector2();
    pointer.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth)*2-1;
    pointer.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) *2+1;
    cast.setFromCamera(pointer,camera);
    const inter = cast.intersectObject(grupa,true);
    
    console.log('ssss',inter[0].object.id);
    
    
    
    // console.log(inter[0].normal.x)
    if(stat == 0 && stat1 == 0 && stat2 == 0){

        inter[0].object.material.color.set('black');
        
        if (inter[0].object.id == 11){
            stat++;
        }else if(inter[0].object.id == 13){
            stat1++
        }else if(inter[0].object.id == 14){
            stat2++
        };
        
        
        new TWEEN.Tween(inter[0].object.position).to({
            x:0,
            y:0,
            z:3,
        },Math.random()*1000+1000).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut).start();
    
        
        
       
    
             
        
        
    }else{
        // inter[0].object.material.color.set(0x00ff00 );
        console.log(inter)
        if(inter[0].object.id == 11){
            inter[0].object.material.color.set(0x00ff00 );
            new TWEEN.Tween(inter[0].object.position).to({
                x:-3,
                y:0,
                z:0,
            },Math.random()*1000+1000).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut).start();
            stat = 0 ;
        }else if(inter[0].object.id == 13){
            inter[0].object.material.color.set(0x039BCF );
            new TWEEN.Tween(inter[0].object.position).to({
                x:0,
                y:0,
                z:0,
            },Math.random()*1000+1000).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut).start();
            stat1 = 0;
            
        }else if(inter[0].object.id == 14){
            inter[0].object.material.color.set(0x50D445 );
            new TWEEN.Tween(inter[0].object.position).to({
                x:3,
                y:0,
                z:0,
            },Math.random()*1000+1000).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut).start();
            stat2 = 0;
        };
        
      
        
       
        
    };
    
    console.log('статус0', stat);
    console.log('статус1', stat1);
    console.log('статус2', stat2);
};














function updateConePosition() {
    let targetX = mouseX / window.innerWidth * 2 - 1;
    
    let targetY = -mouseY / window.innerHeight * 2 + 1;
    let vector = new THREE.Vector3(targetX, targetY, camera.position.z - 1);
    vector.unproject(camera);

    let dir = vector.sub(camera.position).normalize();
    let distance = -camera.position.z / dir.z;
    let pos = camera.position.clone().add(dir.multiplyScalar(distance));

    cone.position.copy(pos);
}




window.addEventListener('click',handclick)
  
scene.add(grupa);
camera.position.z = 5;// позиция камеры по 

let cursor = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    z: 0,
};
const clock = new THREE.Clock();


function animate() { requestAnimationFrame( animate ); 
    
     cube.rotation.x += 0.01; 
     cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
     cube2.rotation.y += 0.01;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
 } 
     animate();


let size = {
    x: window.innerWidth,
    y: window.innerHeight,
};

window.addEventListener('mousemove',(event)=>{
    cursor.x = -(event.clientX / size.x - 0.5);
    cursor.y = (event.clientY / size.y - 0.5);
    camera.lookAt(grupa.position);
});

const tick = ()=>{
    controls.update();
    TWEEN.update();
   


    renderer.render(scene,camera);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    
}
tick()


window.addEventListener('resize', ()=>
{
    size.x = window.innerWidth;
    size.y = window.innerHeight;
    camera.aspect = size.x / size.y;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(size.x,size.y);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio,2));
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
});


window.addEventListener('dblclick',()=>
{
    if(document.fullscreenElement){
        document.exitFullscreen();
    }else{
        canvas.requestFullscreen();
    }
})


В общем решение я нашел, но вопрос оставлю и надеюсь помогу таким как я.
Как я понимаю я искал объект используя:
const inter = cast.intersectObject(grupa,true);

*при этом объекты в группе
из-за этого он возможно и выдавал ошибку
Ну и решение
Кубы я пушнул в список:
let boxs = [];
boxs.push(cube,cube1,cube2);

Заменил:
const inter = cast.intersectObject(grupa);

На:
const inter = cast.intersectObjects(boxs);

И далее через цикл уже делал свои дела:
for(let obj of inter){
        obj.object.material.color.set('white'); // тут типо мой прошлый код, но inter[0] теперь obj
        

Старался по понятнее для чайников как я
